# How do you change "Item 1" to something else on a property list?

Tags: iphone, xcode

For my App I have a property list and I can't figure out how to make it change from "Item 1" or "Item 2" to anything else..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at items in an array.  Array items don't have names, or keys, just ordinal positions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you edit it manually? If not, why would you need to change names?